# Loop through range over cells after each cell is copied print a sheet

Tags: excel, vba, loops, printing

I have made a sheet so someone can record some references for a pallet and a product code. I would the like them to be able to print this as a label I've made on another sheet when they have finished inputting all the data.

I need some code that allow me too loop through a range ("B5:last row") on sheet ("In (New)") and every time it finds a Ref it will copy the values from B(whatever) and the C value next to it and paste it on my label Sheet ("label") in the range ("K17:L17") then print the label out of the default printer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the code module of sheet `In (New)`, I suggest using something like

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub PrintLabels()
    Dim oCell

    'Loop through all cells B5 and below, as long as they're not empty
    For Each oCell In Range("B5", Range("B5").End(xlDown))
        'Copy cell B? and the cell on its right and paste in label!K17
        Range(oCell, oCell.Offset(1)).Copy Sheets("label").Range("K17")

        'Print sheet to the default printer
        Sheets("label").PrintOut
    Next
End Sub
```

This does not work if some cells below `B5` are empty (non-continuous data).
In this case, replace `Range("B5").End(xlDown)` with the following.
It looks for the last row in the sheet containing data.

```vb
"B" & Cells.Find("*", Searchrder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlPrevious).Row
```

---

If you want to adapt your code to match your workbook more accurately, read the following documentation articles:

- [Range](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.range)
- [Copy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.copy)
- [PrintOut](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.sheets.printout)

Comment: Thank you very much! Appreciate you putting the extra links as well! works brilliantly all i had to amend is changing the code from Sheet to Sheets.  Thanks again!

Comment: You're very welcome! My apologies for the sheets, I edited the answer. Try to use this example to understand how VBA works with Excel, it's pretty cool ^^

Comment: No problem at all I'm grateful for the help! and VBA combined with excel is extremely powerful with some help I've already done some things I never knew excel/vba was capable of. Is there any particular site/course you would recommend for someone who has a basic understanding to level it up so can confidently make nice long code(but neat and understandable :) )?

Comment: No, sorry. I mostly learned by trying, reading documentation and threads on SO and other forums ([mrexcel.com](https://mrexcel.com) is quite nice).